# Как получить http-уведомление (платеж) ЮMoney на несколько доменов? (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, http, post, yandex-money

Как получить `http-уведомление` (платеж) ЮMoney на несколько доменов? (wordpress)

На один домен без проблем получается, а вот на другие домены платеж не приходит, видимо из-за того что в `http-уведомлении` можно указать только один домен.

Как делать так, чтобы можно было получить `http-уведомление` для нескольких доменов с одним аккаунтом юmoney?

Пробовал писать такой код:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create([

"http" => [
"method" => $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"],

"header" => "Content-Type: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"],

"content" => file_get_contents("php://input")
]

]);

file_get_contents("https://site1.ru/url.php", false, $ctx);

file_get_contents("https://site2.ru/url.php", false, $ctx);

file_get_contents("https://site3.ru/url.php", false, $ctx);
```

Разместил его в `index.php`, но ничего не происходит. Куда в wordpress будет правильнее разместить такой код, в `functions.php`? Как делать правильно?

Comment: Писать свою страницу, которая будет принимать уведомление и рассылать всем.

Comment: В ВП правильнее [написать плагин](https://codex.wordpress.org/Написание_плагина). см https://wpmag.ru/2014/functions-php/. Только непонятно причём тут ВП вообще.

Comment: Nginx есть? Напишите если есть, в таком случае можно просто зеркалировать запрос на несколько доменов через [mirror](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html) и совсем не писать код.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаток wordpress, однако, если говорите, что для уведомления можно указать только один домен, в таком случае, укажите какой-то сервисный домен, а на нем реализуйте логику отправки на остальные.

Код если честно, может быть до боли прост и реализовать его можно в плагине.

Так же, в [доке ЮMoney](https://yoomoney.ru/docs/payment-buttons/using-api/notifications) сказано, что вам придет POST запрос и данные в формате application/x-www-form-urlencoded, в таком случае, можно написать что-то подобное:

```
foreach (
    [
        'https://site1.ru/url.php',
        'https://site2.ru/url.php',
        'https://site3.ru/url.php'
    ] as $url
) {
    // parse request
    $requestData = [];
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $requestData);

    // send requests
    $cURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $cURL, 
        [
            CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_POST            => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $requestData
        ]
    );
    $response = curl_exec($cURL);
    // обрабатываем ответ от других ваших доменов
    if (is_bool($response)) { // т.к. строка может быть пустой, а функция вернет string|bool, по факту это string|false
        // где-то выше ловите это исключение и в logger его
        throw new \DomainException('Received a bad response from url: ' . $url);
    }
    curl_close($cURL);
}
```

Дока по созданию плагина: https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/how-to-create-your-first-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Мне кажется, или json_decode() не согласуется с `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Возможно, перепутали с уведомлениями от ЮKassa?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Ага, благодарю, поправил (смотрел в две разные доки)

Comment: Так же, хочется сказать, что логика с выбросом исключений здесь возможно не совсем хорошая идея, т.к., если вы не смогли достучаться до одного домена, то отправка на остальные не произойдет, в таком случае, стоит обернуть все в `try...catch` прям в цикле и складывать возникшие исключения в массив и после обрабатывать. По идее, это bad practice, в том же классе/функции кидать и ловить исключения, но в данном контексте, это оправдано, т.к. вы можете захотеть получать ошибки в структурированном виде относительно каждого домена, а это как раз ответственность исключений.

Comment: Здесь можно вообще без исключений. Если не удалось отправить, то следует сохранить сообщение и пытаться отправить его в следующий раз.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Да, разумеется, это уже бизнес и вкусовщина.

Comment: 1. Вынесите `$requestData ... parse_str...` за пределы цикла. 2. `DmainException` - орф. ошибка